# Excel for mac Forms button not running macro

Tags: excel, vba, forms

I have a spreadsheets with multiple macros, several of them have a forms button to run it and those are working fine, however when I created a new macro and then a new Forms button to assign it to, that button does not seem to want to work.  When I click on it, it seems to stay in "edit mode" allowing me to resize, move or edit text.  The other forms buttons on the same page work perfectly fine, and I'm quite sure I created all of these buttons the same way.  Any suggestions on how to get this button to execute the macro when pressed?

Comment: Exit design mode: [Select or deselect controls on a worksheet](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/select-or-deselect-controls-on-a-worksheet-c4333a13-5a39-485c-af13-5d23440faed4?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: I think you're absolutely right, however I can't seem to find how to do this on the Excel for Mac version.  There isn't a Design Mode button on the Developer ribbon, the only place it shows up is in the VB Editor and I've exited design mode there.  Any advice on how to do this with the Mac version of Excel?